# Select the current entity with a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft java edition, `@s` stands for "current entity" and works only if you type in chat.

Is there any other way to use the current entity on command block? `@s` doesn't work there.

Comment: I know thats why asking is any other option there @p but in multiplayer nearest player getting that

Answer (score 1):

`@s` stands for self (I suppose) and can be set trough `as <target>` inside `execute` commands.

You are able to do as such:

```
execute as @a run say I am @s
```

The command `say I am @s` will run once for each target in `execute as @a` (In this case, every player) and `@s` will change for each player on each iteration. For example, let us say there are 3 players ingame, `Ast`, `Bor` and `Cro`. `execute as @a` will act as if each player had typed in their own chat `say I am @s` resulting in each player type their own name in chat:

```
[Ast] I am Ast
[Bor] I am Bor
[Cro] I am Cro
```

Similary, If you use relative positions (`~ ~ ~` or `^ ^ ^`), these can be set trough `at <target>`. You can do for example `execute as @a at @s` which will iterate each player, making `@s` and relative position use those of the player.